# I'm getting a NoSuchMethodError when trying to use Guice AOP

Tags: websphere, aop, guice

I'm trying to use Guice AOP for profiling:

```
@Override
protected void configure()
{
    this.bindInterceptor(Matchers.any(), Matchers.annotatedWith(Profiled.class), new ProfileInterceptor());
}
```

It's working fine locally, but when I try to deploy to Websphere Application Server, I get a

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: cnphi/base/profiling/ProfilingModule.bindInterceptor(Lcom/google/inject/matcher/Matcher;Lcom/google/inject/matcher/Matcher;[Lorg/aopalliance/intercept/MethodInterceptor;)
```

Any idea what's happening here?

Comment: The no-aop version of Guice is probably on the classpath somewhere.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm guessing. Any idea how to force it to use the version I want instead?

Comment: You should analyse your dependency tree. For maven that's: mvn dependency:tree

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error when I updated the Transaction API dependency, from the old Oracle (javax) one:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.transaction-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

To the current Eclipse / Jakarta one, latest 1.3.x:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.transaction</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.transaction-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.3</version> <!-- causes Guice NoSuchMethodError -->
    </dependency>
```

The fix was to "downgrade" and use 1.3.1 instead, which is closer to the 1.3 javax version:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.transaction</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.transaction-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
```